# How to get ngrams with word2phrase function in wordVectors package in R?

Tags: r, word2vec

I want to use the word2phrase() function in the wordVectors package to generate some ngrams for subsequent training using train_word2vec().

```
library(wordVectors)
word2phrase(train_file="txt.csv", output_file="ngrams.txt", min_count=10, threshold=50, force=TRUE)
```

The first time I run it, I got the following output message:

```
Vocab size (unigrams + bigrams): 20868
Words in train file: 193569
```

The second time I run it, I got the following output message:

```
Vocab size (unigrams + bigrams): 20868
Words in train file: 258092
```

So every time I run it, the "Words in train file" keeps increasing, while "Vocab size" stays the same. But when I check the output file "ngrams.txt", nothing really changes: I only have 1-gram and 2-grams in the file. How can I have n-grams stored in "ngrams.txt"?

Answer (score 0):

To compute n-grams, you need to run word2phrase n-1 times successively.

After the first run, you have a vocabulary 1-grams and 2-grams. The second run, working from the output of the first run, can create 2-grams from words in the previous vocabulary so you can create 3-grams (and even 4-grams I guess if it creates a bi-gram of 2 bi-grams).

Thankfully, this is already implemented in the function `prep_word2vec`.

You can simply run:

```r
library("wordVectors")

max_n_grams <- 4

prep_word2vec("txt.csv", "ngrams.txt", bundle_ngrams = max_n_grams, 
              min_count=10, threshold=50, force=TRUE)
```